# "The response is in wrong format" error in (magento core) DHL shipping module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-ce, dhl

I've scoured the Internet and asked on numerous forums for 2 months looking for an answer to this problem and only gotten 1 response that had nothing to do with the problem.

The DHL shipping module refuses to work in all latest releases of Magento.

Even on a fresh install of 1.7, 1.8, and 1.9 and only enabling it without configuring any other setting it refuses to work and keeps spitting this error in return for all versions:

2014-07-24T13:12:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => String could not be parsed as XML
    [1] => The response is in wrong format.
    [__pid] => 25540
)

Simply enabling it and nothing else DHL never comes up as a shipping option and only reports that it's not available.

There is nothing on the Internet specifically about this issue which is blowing my mind because it's bugged in all of the CE releases. It can't be that no one is using the DHL shipping module.

Comment: What do you mean by "only enabling it without configuring any other setting"?

Comment: Enabling it for checkout in the admin without supplying any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to use the DHL modules without any credentials. In order to make it work you should ask DHL for the credentials.

I cant find official documentation, but [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-shipping-methods-dhl) and [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/shipping-carriers-dhl) is something similar for Magento Go. Give it a read and you will notice you are missing all the information from DHL and the DHL module does not work without the proper credentials.

Comment: It's the same result with or without credentials.

Comment: Here is the error produced in system.log

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: ^  in /app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php on line 810

Comment: So you are stating you have the DHL credentials and you followed each step to gain access to their endpoint and still nothing? Do you have a guide about the process to get the DHL credentials for me to read?

Comment: Yes I have the credentials provided by DHL api support. I don't know anything about a guide.

Comment: The DHL error logs keep returning the XML string with no indication of any problem which is weird. The first error states that Array ( [0] => String could not be parsed as XML which is leading me to guess there is something bugged with the XML portion of it. I have no clue.

Comment: No bug has been filled for this module, so i think it has something to do with your config and probably with an error of communication between your server and DHL

Comment: I don't see how the configs can be the problem since they're set out of the box. The credentials are good and have been double checked with DHL. What kind of error could occur between the hosting company and the DHL server that would prevent the magento supplied module from working? Everything else works fine.

Comment: Maybe a white list on the DHL side, i saw that in other providers. But since i dont have the documentation i cant be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is anything but the response XML from DHL doesn't specify UTF-8 encoding. There's also this error in the XML return: [CDATA[The required node <ID> is missing, empty, or contains a value that is not the correct data type.